# Extract exact coordinates of points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinates, arcgis-10.4

I am using ArcGIS and have a shapefile with data points. They have UTM x and y coordinates, so I can plot them in ArcGIS with "Display XY data". Now I saw that many points are not exactly on the road, so I used the snap tool to fix that. Now I need the new coordinates, because the coordinates in the original Excel sheet of course did not change with the snapping.

Is there a way to extract the NEW coordinates?

Comment: "extract", do you want these updated coordinates in the shapefile or exported back to Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Add Geometry Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm):

> Adds new attribute fields to the input features representing the
>   spatial or geometric characteristics and location of each feature,
>   such as length or area and x-, y-, z-, and m-coordinates.

With geometry property POINT_X_Y_Z_M:

> POINT_X: The x-coordinate of the point.
>
> POINT_Y: The y-coordinate of the point.
>
> POINT_Z: The z-coordinate of the point. This field is only added if
>   the input features are z-enabled.
>
> POINT_M: The m-coordinate of the point. This field is only added if
>   the input features are m-enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The new coordinates are part of the intrinsic geometry. If you want to have them visible in the attribute table, you can use the [Add XY Coordinates](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-xy-coordinates.htm) tool.

The fields you add are static, i.e. they won't be updated if you modify your geometry again.

Answer (score 1):

First, please check that your shapefile coordinate system is the same as your map coordinate system because maybe this causes the un-compatibility position of your points with the road.

Then to calculate new coordinates, open the attribute table of the points shapefile after editing positions

add a new field for coord x and a new field for coord y>> name it and chooses units and type.

Then calculate geometry >> calculate coordinates.

PS. also check your map units.